# What happens if I SELECT something AS a name then something else AS the same name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I've already answered my question but didn't see it on here, so here we go.  Please feel free to link to the question if it has been asked exactly.
I simplified my question to the following code:

```
SELECT 'a' AS col1, 'b' AS col1
```

Will this give a same column name error?

Will the last value always be returned or is there a chance col1 could be 'a'?

Comment: Why don't you just try it yourself and see?

Comment: why would you want too?  that just seems like bad practice

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL "I've already answered my question but didn't see it on here"  Based on his last question, I'm guessing he found some weird gotcha situation...

Comment: @Robert Probably bad practice, but Microsoft did it with `sp_who2`, which returns two columns both named `SPID`.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson your right they did but if you look at the procedure code it clearly states there is no practical reason this would be done.  It's only done for right scrolling or usability.

Comment: I am not saying that it is good practice, only that I found that it didn't return an error, as I expected.  I was more curious if the order of operation would be the same every time.  IE, given a list of things AS col1, would col1 be the same every time?

Comment: @Michael Fredrickson I did find that it doesn't return an error, but I didn't do extensive tests for consistency in the result.  And I'm aware sometimes SQL results aren't guaranteed in the same order unless specified in an ORDER BY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works in the final query:

[image]

However when you do it in a subselect and refer to the ambiguous column aliases in an outer query you get an error:

[image]

Comment: A "subselect" is called an in line view.

Comment: @Glenn, no, only in Oracle speak.

Comment: Ok, and the other part of my question meant is there some weird unknown order of operation where it may return the first, middle, or last occurance of AS col1?

Comment: @MiloLaMar, all occurrences of `as col1` will be returned in the outer select, in the subselect you'll just get an error.

Comment: @Johan It was interesting to find out the behavior in subsequent versions of SQL Server, Oracle, and MySQL, but it seems in SQL Server 2000 (R3 or R4, I can't remember), it returns a single occurrence of col1 (or 'a' as it is in your answer). And so far, `sql-server-2000` has always returned the last value assigned to it rather than renaming subsequent occurrences by appending a number to them.

Comment: Oh, I I think i'm wrong there.  I'm just overwriting array indicies with my php display.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you would ever want this, but I tried it in Oracle (10g) and it worked fine, returning both columns.  I realize you've asked about SQL Server specifically, but I found it interesting that this worked at all.

Edit: It also works on MySQL.

Comment: and sql-server 2008. Also both values will be returned in the resultset.

Comment: @Todd Nice to know that it works differently in Oracle. In `sql-server` it returns a single column, so I asked the second part of my question "Whether you can expect the same order of operation every time or not."  I'll take the time to do some testing later if noone beats me to it.

Comment: Nevermind, I believe I'm just seeing the result of overwriting the value in the same array index because of the way I'm viewing my results.

Answer (score 2):

In `SQL 2008 r2` it is valid as a stand alone query. Under certain circumstances it will produce errors (incomplete list):

- Inline views
- Common Table Entries
- Stored Procedures when the output is used by reporting services and presumably similarly integrated tools

It's hard to imagine a case where you would *want* duplicate row names, and it's easy to think of ways in which writing queries with repeats now could turn sour in the future.

Comment: Very good point, @Glenn.  I wouldn't do this as a practice myself, I've just ran into a situation where I saw this happening from dyno-generated SQL and wasn't sure about what behavior to expect.